# Semantical Error - line 0, col 14 near 'AppBundle\\Repository\\User': Error: Class 'AppBundle\\Repository\\User' is not defined

Tags: php, symfony

I have two classes User and UserMobile with relation one to one

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserMobile")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_mobile_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user_mobile;
.....................................................................
/**
     * Set user_mobile.
     *
     * @param \stdClass $user_mobile
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUserMobile($user_mobile): User
    {
        $this->user_mobile = $user_mobile;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get UserMobile.
     *
     * @return UserMobile
     */
    public function getUserMobile()
    {
        return $this->user_mobile;
    }
```

And class UserMobile:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * UserMobile
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_mobile")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserMobileRepository")
 */
class UserMobile
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="user_mobile")
     */
    private $user;
```

I have two objects UserMobile $user_mobile and User $user. I want to create relation between this two objects.  I do following:

```
$user->setUserMobile($userMobile);
            $this->em->persist($user);
            $this->em->persist($userMobile);
            $this->em->flush();
```

I get error **"[Semantical Error] line 0, col 14 near 'AppBundle\Repository\User': Error: Class 'AppBundle\Repository\User' is not defined.",
                "class": "Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException",**

Comment: Did you intentionally leave out the namespace for your User entity?  And do you actually have a UserRepository class?

Comment: no, i have namespace. i updated question. Yes, I have UserRepository class in AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository.php

Comment: Please update your question with the content of the UserRepository class. Seems to me that you use a User object as parameter in a method while you dit not wrote "use AppBundle\Entity\User;"

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have AppBundle\Repository\User instead of UserRepository or possibly instead of AppBundle\Entity\User.  I don't see it in your posted code.  Probably in your controller.  An unrelated issue is that UserMobile::setUser is never being called in your test case.